# Awk to check the current field being processed

Tags: awk, gawk

Is it possible to check the current field being processed.

```
awk '/pattern/{print field where pattern found}' #Howto
```

Comment: What if multiple fields match the pattern?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '/pattern/{for(i=1;$i!~/pattern/;i++); print i}' file
```

In case of multiple matches it only returns the first field of match. Let's take it for a spin:

```
$ cat file
A  1 A1g DELL
A  1 B1s HP
A  7 HP HP
A  5 Jgf KIT
A  1 Def JOP
$ awk '/HP/{for(i=1;$i!~/HP/;i++); print i}' file
4
3
```

Comment: Actually the `/pattern/{example}` stuff was just an example, I'm more concentrating on the general case

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built-in way to get the field number where the match occurred but you can do it using a loop:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) if ($i ~ /pattern/) print i }' file
```

This prints all fields that match the pattern.